# How to find which components are conflicting?

Tags: angular

I'm using ES5 flavor of Angular 2. 
And I've encountered this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
Conflicting components: class2,class6 ("
    </tbody>
</table>
[ERROR ->]<paging [data]="data" (changed)="loadCountries($event)" unit="country"></paging>
<md-spinner class="lis"): class18@30:0 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

It says `class2` and `class6`. I can't find out the original names of the classes.

Here's my module definition:

```
var module = ng.core.NgModule({
    imports: [
        ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule, 
        ng.router.RouterModule.forRoot([].concat([...])), 
        ng.material.MaterialModule, 
        ng.http.HttpModule, 
        ng.common.CommonModule, 
        ng.forms.FormsModule],
    declarations: [
        app.CoalAddWorldCoalSupply, 
        app.FilterValuesDialog, 
        app.CoalFlows, 
        app.ImportWorldCoalSupplies, 
        app.CoalProducts, 
        app.CoalReports, 
        app.CoalUpsertFlow, 
        app.CoalUpsertProduct, 
        app.CoalWorldCoalSupplies, 
        app.CountryList, 
        app.CountryUpsert, 
        app.Dashboard, 
        app.ElectricityHeatGenerations, 
        ...
        ],
    entryComponents: [app.FilterValuesDialog, confirmDialog],
    bootstrap: [app.Layout],
    providers: [globalService]
})
.Class({
    constructor: function () { }
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ng.platformBrowserDynamic
      .platformBrowserDynamic()
      .bootstrapModule(module);
});
```

Parts specified with `...` means more of the same things.

How to understand which class `zone.js` is referring to?

Answer (score 16):

Let's say we have the following app:

**app.component.js**

```typescript
app.AppComponent = Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:
    '<h1>(es5) angular2 4.1.3</h1><comp1></comp1>'
})
.Class({
  constructor: function AppComponent() {}
});
```

**component1.js**

```typescript
app.Component1 = Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  template:
    'component1'
})
.Class({
  constructor: function Component1() {}
});
```

**component2.js**

```typescript
app.Component2 = Component({
  selector: 'comp1',
  template:
    'component2'
})
.Class({
  constructor: function Component2() {}
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AKBVbX9ruZM8DchFcfbh?p=preview

So my actions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for making that gif and showing how to debug and find the conflicting components. I would not have figured that out on my own. For my issue, I was importing a UI library which was exporting MatButtonModule, but so was my main project. By debugging like this I was able to find that both the UI library was exporting MatButtonModule and this was creating a conflict as now my project had two es5.js files that were competing to render this material Module

Comment: I admit I had to watch the debug gif several times to see what you were doing, my only wish is that it was not running so fast, but none the less I was able to follow and finally figure it out.