# angular testing, conflicting component selectors

Tags: angular, testing

In an angular application unit test I would like to replace an imported component with a stub-component. I must import the module that defines the component because other components from it are required for the test.
Simiar question: [How to find which components are conflicting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586857/how-to-find-which-components-are-conflicting)
How can I import all components from a module but some? Like a whitelist or blacklist of components.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule, 
     /*Contains RichTextBoxComponent with selector 'app-rich-text-box'.
       How to import all components from this module but 'app-rich-text-box'.
     */
    UicompsModule],
  declarations: [ 
    ManageQuestionComponent, 
    /*Contains also a selector 'app-rich-text-box'*/
    StubRichTextBoxComponent],
  providers: [  ],
})
.compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself:

```
 .overrideModule(UicompsModule, {
      remove: {
              exports: [RichTextBoxComponent]
          },
     })
```